# Debian 9 Stretch 3.5mm jack not working

Tags: linux, debian, audio

Recently, I installed Debian 9 Stretch (dual booting with windows 10 using grub). Everything works fine for now, except my headphones.

The PulseAudio 'Volume Control' interface detects my headphones fine.

So does running `alsamixer` in the terminal. Even when I put on some music, the volume gage becomes active with a blue bar as if audio was coming through. But no sound coming through the headphones. I went back to windows 10 to definitively see if my 3.5mm jack on my laptop was the problem (or my headphones), and it works fine with windows 10.

It's a Debian.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

PS. Sound works fine coming from my internal laptop speakers once I disconnect my headphones.

Comment: It's often a driver issue solved with a newer kernel. You could try [stretch-backport](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/)'s [linux-image-amd64](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/linux-image-amd64) currently pointing to [linux-image-4.19.0-0.bpo.1-amd64](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/linux-image-4.19.0-0.bpo.1-amd64). This is worth a try even if sometimes changes in the pulseaudio or alsa userland parts are also required

Comment: Also check there: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/HP-spectre-x360-on-linux/td-p/4980797 and the other link https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/HP-spectre-x360-on-linux/m-p/5122160#M66839 . Problem is the same, but it's from 2015 so ...

Comment: Hey, @A.B thanks for your comments. I tried the solutions described in those links but to no avail. Before I ditch Linux all together and get back to Windows, might you suggest a different Linux Distro that is perhaps more suited toward laptops and less driver/hardware related configurations? I was thinking Ubuntu, but I've seen similar problems and since it's based on Debian, I might not fare any better there.

Comment: You should check mailing lists about linux sound/alsa etc. and perhaps see how to submit a problem (this might not be easy). If one distribution did solve it cleanly, then it would be adopted on upstream and others: that's what open source is for. So chances are it wasn't reported loudly enough so nothing was made to correct the (unknown to kernel/alsa/whatever developpers) problem.

Comment: You're perhaps not alone: https://superuser.com/questions/1360320/linux-no-sound-on-headphone-jack . But at the same time you didn't put the most important thing in the question: your hardware exact model

Answer (score 1):

Just for the records, I had the same problem. I run:
    `sudo alsactl init`
and them all my sound settings were renewed.